# how to modify a df from 1 column 52 rows to 4 columns and 13 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df, like this:

```
     0   1   2   3
0   2s  2h  2d  2c
1   3s  3h  3d  3c
2   4s  4h  4d  4c
3   5s  5h  5d  5c
4   6s  6h  6d  6c
5   7s  7h  7d  7c
6   8s  8h  8d  8c
7   9s  9h  9d  9c
8   Ts  Th  Td  Tc
9   Js  Jh  Jd  Jc
10  Qs  Qh  Qd  Qc
11  Ks  Kh  Kd  Kc
12  As  Ah  Ad  Ac
```

How can I add a number to the index? ( I need columns from 1-4 and rows from 1-13)

Comment: you can use this way : df.set_index(['1', '2','3','4']) see in this document https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: the title don't match the question in description

Answer (score 0):

assign new values to index and column using range

```
df.index = range(1, len(df)+1 ) 
df.columns = range(1, len(df.columns)+1)
df
```

```
    1   2   3   4
1   2s  2h  2d  2c
2   3s  3h  3d  3c
3   4s  4h  4d  4c
4   5s  5h  5d  5c
5   6s  6h  6d  6c
6   7s  7h  7d  7c
7   8s  8h  8d  8c
8   9s  9h  9d  9c
9   Ts  Th  Td  Tc
10  Js  Jh  Jd  Jc
11  Qs  Qh  Qd  Qc
12  Ks  Kh  Kd  Kc
13  As  Ah  Ad  Ac
```